# math.h methods working different?

Tags: c, math.h

I've tried some calculations on c, my code is below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    float a = 1.8;
    float b = 3.3;
    float c = 1.5;
    float d = 5.9;
    float e = 2.6;

    float result = a / (a + (abs(a - b) / (b + (pow(c, 5) / (e + (pow(d, 2) / (b + (pow(c, 3) / 4))))))));
    float result2 = a / (a + ((-1) * (a-b)) / (b + ((c * c * c * c * c) / (e + ((d * d) / (b + ((c * c * c) / 4)))))));
    printf("Result  = %.4f\n", result);
    printf("Result2 = %.4f\n", result2);
    system("pause");
    return(0);
}
```

Result2 is the correct result. So why result and result2 are different? What am i doing is wrong here?

Comment: can you share the results

Comment: `abs(a - b)` is != `(-1) * (a-b)`

Comment: @wrangler For the current settings of a and b, yes, it equals

Comment: of course @Haris result = 0.8778 and result2 = 0.8272

Comment: result2 is correct result by the way

Comment: @wrangler you're mistaken, they are equal

Comment: @CemSönmez: no; it is you, not @wrangler, who is mistaken.  Since `abs()` takes and returns an `int`, the expression `(-1) * (a - b)` yields `1.5`, but `abs(a - b)` yields `1`.  You could see this by printing the values yourself, carefully.

Comment: `abs(a - b)` is **not `(-1) * (a-b)` if a > b

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`abs` is for `int`:

```
int abs(int j);
```

while `fabs` or `fabsf` is what you shall use:

```
double fabs(double x);
float fabsf(float x);
```

**EDITED:**

After changing `abs` to `fabs`, a local test gives:

```
[pengyu@GLaDOS tmp]$ gcc a.c -lm -Wall -pedantic
[pengyu@GLaDOS tmp]$ ./a.out 
Result  = 0.8272
Result2 = 0.8272
```